# Good introduction to INSPIRE?

Tags: web-mapping, wms, standards

Can anyone point me to a good introduction to the INSPIRE directive? I know it's basically WMS 1.3 with added bells and whistles but now I'm back in Europe I should probably find out what they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say its a bit more than WMS 1.3. I assume you already checked these, but if not have a look at the [About Inspire](http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/index.cfm/pageid/48) on the Inspire website for a brief overview and also the AGI [Inspire Overview Document](http://www.agi.org.uk/storage/inspire/inspire_intro.pdf) as starting points

Answer (score 4):

For French readers, [Marc Leobet](http://georezo.net/blog/inspire/) wrote and published a [nice introduction to INSPIRE](http://georezo.net/blog/inspire/files/2011/03/Inspire_neophytes_V2.pdf) (Second edition).

See [associated post](http://georezo.net/blog/inspire/2011/02/28/inspire-pour-les-neophytes-2eme-edition/).

Answer (score 2):

http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/index.cfm

Intro to the geospatial

http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/index.cfm/pageid/2

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to use this as a forum to promote our own product, but my employer (Safe Software) is holding a webinar on July 21st on [Harmonising Your Spatial Data for INSPIRE with FME](http://www.safe.com/learning/webinars/#upcoming). The presenter is knowledgeable and so this may be a good introduction to INSPIRE as a whole, whether or not you use our products.